# Is there a DocuSign API listitems attribute to allow multiselect from a dropdown list on a document?

Tags: docusignapi

I have 18 checkboxes on my document that I want to list in a dropdown where multiple values can be selected.

Is there an API listitems attribute to make the dropdown a multiselect?  I have looked but could not find it in API.  It looks like it is available in Connect but we are not using that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with the eSignature REST API. Dropdown tabs can only allow the user to select a single value and if you want the user to select multiple values you would need to use checkboxes like you indicated in the question.

According to [this article](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?&rsc_301=&bundleId=uqj1643324072491&topicId=mnq1576610159412.html), it looks like this is an option with document generation in DocuSign CLM, but not through the eSignature REST API.